# Android carriage return inside concatenated string

Tags: android, textview, concatenation, carriage-return

A quick question please.

I am reading an NFC tag and showing the result on the screen of my device and this is how it appears:

```
The content of the tag is : bla bla bla
```

I want to have 2 lines appearing as this:

```
The content of the tag is : 

bla bla bla
```

I added

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

inside the TextView definition, but now although I do have 2 lines, it's not cut where I would like it to be because I get this :

```
The content of the tag is : bla

bla bla
```

Many people around talk about `\n` and `\r` but I don't understand how to integrate them inside my textView because it's a concatenation :

```
 TextView.setText("The content of the tag is :  " + result);
```

Any tip? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
 TextView.setText("Tag is :\n" + result);
```

or if necessary

```
 TextView.setText("Tag is :\n" + result.replaceAll("[^\\w]+", " "));
```

It just replaces any group of character which are not letter or digit by a space.

Comment: Hi Mederic, It doesn't work for me as it doesn't put my bla bla bla on a second line. Any idea why not ?
PS: What it does is exactly what you say. My time goes from 10:50:22 to 10 50 22 and if I put emoticons it doesn't show them.

Comment: nope, I also tried \r and then \n\r. It doesn't do anything so far

Comment: Apologies, I am an idiot. :-)
I was messing around and I had removed the
android:singleLine="false"
Your \n works perfectly. Thank you. 
By the way, also French?